# How can i adjust height using screenheight?

Tags: jquery

I want to adjust height of an image using screen.height.I tried this but i dont get any change in the size of the image.the size of the image is the size of the browser.

```
      var screenHeight = screen.height;
     $('.image').css('height',(screenHeight*0.9/100));
```

Comment: How small do you want the image?  screenHeight*0.9/100 is essentially the same as screenHeight*0.009.

Comment: my screen ht is 768px, i want it 550px..

Comment: So you should do something like $('.image').height(screenHeight/1.4); , right?  Here's the jsfiddle for that - http://jsfiddle.net/b5Kse/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use

```
$(window).height();
```

Check out below snippet:

```
var screenHeight = $(window).height();
$('.image').css('height',(screenHeight*0.9/100));
```

I have changed only screen height to window height. That will resize your image as per window size. You can consider your own expression in setting image height. You just need to put window height only.!

Mark as answer if you find your solution.!

Comment: i want to calculate it based on screen resolution, it should be the same on differant systems..

Comment: I see. So you can screen.height here. screen.height * 71 / 100 will result your 550px height of image.

Answer (score 0):

```
var screenHeight = screen.height;
     $('.image').css('height',(screenHeight*0.9/100)+"px");
```

Comment: "px" is not needed for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If making the picture ridiculously tiny is your goal, it works just fine for me in Firefox and webkit browsers.
   http://jsfiddle.net/b5Kse/

```
$(function() {
  var screenHeight = screen.height;
   $('.image').css('height',(screenHeight*0.9/100));
});
```